# How to close browser window in Perl

Tags: perl

I have the following code to open a browser in Perl

```
$IE = Win32::OLE->new("InternetExplorer.Application");
$IE->{visible} = 1; #BTW what is visible doing here?
$IE->Navigate("http://google.com");
# Now I want to close the current window, how would I do this?
```

I tried:

`$IE->close();` and `$IE->close;`

Nothing happened.

Comment: You might be doing work for nothing by not using [Win32::IE::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::IE::Mechanize) or [Win32::IEAutomation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::IEAutomation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this I have tested it and it works:

```
    $IE->Quit();
```